# Bold text inside a flex container not appearing inline

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got div containers that are using flex. I have a bold senescence inside my flex child containers.

example

> **Lorem ipsum dolor** sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc at lectus vitae libero pulvinar fringilla. Nullam vel vestibulum orci.

However, when I create my flex container it's not making the bold text inline. It's creating a block between the regular text and the bold text.

example

> **Lorem ipsum dolor**
>
> sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc at lectus vitae libero
>   pulvinar fringilla. Nullam vel vestibulum orci.

I've set my flex container as follows:

```
.flexparent { display: flex; flex-direction: row; justifty-content: center; flex-wrap: wrap-reverse }
.flexchild1 { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-contetn: center; width: 65%; margin-right: 4%;}
.flexchild2 { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-contetn: center; width: 35%;}
```

My ideal solution is something like this where `.flexchild1` is green and `.flexchild2` is yellow.

[image]

Comment: How do you make "Lorem ipsum dolor" bold

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're going to use a flex container, keep in mind that *all child elements* will become flex items and stack vertically or horizontally, depending on `flex-direction`.

So, if we consider this code:

`<div class="flex-container"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b> consectetur adipiscing elit. <span>Nunc at lectus vitae libero</span> pulvinar fringilla. <i>Nullam vel vestibulum orci.</i></div>`

Although, the `<b>`, `<span>` and `<i>` elements are inline-level in a [*block formatting content*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#block-formatting)...

```css
.flex-container {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

span { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b> consectetur adipiscing elit. <span>Nunc at lectus vitae libero</span> pulvinar fringilla. <i>Nullam vel vestibulum orci.</i></div>
```

ALL child elements are *blockified* in a [*flex formatting context*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)...

```css
.flex-container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.flex-container2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
span { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container1"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b> consectetur adipiscing elit. <span>Nunc at lectus vitae libero</span> pulvinar fringilla. <i>Nullam vel vestibulum orci.</i></div>

<hr>

<div class="flex-container2"><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b> consectetur adipiscing elit. <span>Nunc at lectus vitae libero</span> pulvinar fringilla. <i>Nullam vel vestibulum orci.</i></div>
```

What you may want to do is wrap your text in its own block-level container within the flex container.

```css
.flex-container1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

.flex-container2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

span {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container1">
    <div>
        <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b> consectetur adipiscing elit. <span>Nunc at lectus vitae libero</span> pulvinar fringilla. <i>Nullam vel vestibulum orci.</i>
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="flex-container2">
    <div>
        <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b> consectetur adipiscing elit. <span>Nunc at lectus vitae libero</span> pulvinar fringilla. <i>Nullam vel vestibulum orci.</i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Micheal this has helped me allot. I will take in your advise for the future when I'm working on flex element. Really appreciated your help!